# Add items to a collection if the collection does NOT already contain it by comparing a property of the items?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, contains

Basically, how do I make it so I can do something similar to: `CurrentCollection.Contains(...)`, except by comparing if the item's property is already in the collection?

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 bar;
}


ICollection<Foo> CurrentCollection;
ICollection<Foo> DownloadedItems;

//LINQ: Add any downloaded items where the bar Foo.bar is not already in the collection?
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You start by finding which elements are not already in the collection:

```
var newItems = DownloadedItems.Where(x => !CurrentCollection.Any(y => x.bar == y.bar));
```

And then just add them:

```
foreach(var item in newItems)
{
    CurrentCollection.Add(item);
}
```

Note that the first operation may have quadratic complexity if the size of `DownloadedItems` is close to the size of `CurrentCollection`. If that ends up causing problems (measure first!), you can use a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to bring the complexity down to linear:

```
// collect all existing values of the property bar
var existingValues = new HashSet<Foo>(from x in CurrentCollection select x.bar);
// pick items that have a property bar that doesn't exist yet
var newItems = DownloadedItems.Where(x => !existingValues.Contains(x.bar));
// Add them
foreach(var item in newItems)
{
    CurrentCollection.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Using the hash-map method made my method 5x faster.

Comment: I think this is the best practice

Answer (score 24):

You can use [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

It will compare the two lists and return elements that appear only in the first list.

```
CurrentCollection.AddRange(DownloadedItems.Except(CurrentCollection));
```

Answer (score 16):

Using R.Martinho Fernandes method and converting to 1 line:

```
CurrentCollection.AddRange(DownloadedItems.Where(x => !CurrentCollection.Any(y => y.bar== x.bar)));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call the `Any` method and pass a value to compare to whatever property of the type of object in the collection

```
if (!CurrentCollection.Any(f => f.bar == someValue))
{
    // add item
}
```

a more complete solution could be:

```
DownloadedItems.Where(d => !CurrentCollection.Any(c => c.bar == d.bar)).ToList()
    .ForEach(f => CurrentCollection.Add(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `All`

```
CurrentCollection
    .AddRange(DownloadedItems.Where(x => CurrentCollection.All(y => y.bar != x.bar)));
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you can do also i think it is the easiest way is to une a HashSet instead of a List, by default the HashSet don't add redundant values.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<int> current = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
    List<int> add = new List<int> { 2, 3 };
    current.AddRange(add.Except(current));
```

This will result in 1,2,3, using the default comparing.
This will also work for `Foo` if you change the compare behaviour:

```
    public class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
    {
        public Int32 bar;
        public bool Equals(Foo other)
        {
            return bar == other.bar;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Foo);
        public override int GetHashCode() => (bar).GetHashCode(); // (prop1,prop2,prop3).GetHashCode()
    }
```

You could also implement an `IEqualityComparer<Foo>`, and pass it as second parameter to except

```
    current.AddRange(add.Except(current, new FooComparer()));

    public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
    {
        public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
        {
            return x.bar.Equals(y.bar);
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
        {
            return obj.bar.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newItems = DownloadedItems.Where(i => !CurrentCollection.Any(c => c.Attr == i.Attr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
CurrentCollection.Any(x => x.bar == yourGivenValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal static class ExtensionMethod
{
    internal static ICollection<T> AddIfExists<T>(this ICollection<T> list, ICollection<T> range)
    {
        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            if (!list.Contains(item))
                list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

ICollection<Foo> CurrentCollection;
ICollection<Foo> DownloadedItems;

CurrentCollection.AddIfExists(DownloadedItems)....
```